# Customize the UI in the OSRM frontend

Tags: osrm

I am running the frontend and backend modules for `OSRM`. I want to make some customizations for the web interface and connect it to the backend functions. In which part of the project should I make these changes?

Comment: Did you install osrm-frontend by npm?

Comment: @komeilmajidi Yes, I did

Comment: Ok you have edited html css js files?

Comment: @komeilmajidi I mean changing the layout views, not only the style, such as the form that used to get the location and make the geocoding function.

Comment: All layouts are web-based and displayed in the browser. All sections can be changed through html css js